# How to extract multiple values matching a pattern after a specific keyword?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Would need help on how to extract the multiple passport numbers matching after a passport keyword using a regex's

Text:

```
my friends passport numbers are V123456, V123457 and V123458
```

Regex:

```
(?<=passport)\s*(?:\w+\s){0,10}\s*(\b[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\b)
```

Expected matches output:

```
V123456
V123457
V123458
```

Actual output:

```
V123456
```

Comment: If you know the string is exactly following a certain pattern it will be most accurate to reproduce it, e.g. [`(?:\G(?!^)(?:, | and )|\bpassport numbers are )([a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/t8n375/2) This will never skip over anything other than `passport numbers are` and the following number-pattern connected by the specified separators `(?:, | and )` and is efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely on a lookbehind here since you would need a pattern of an indefinite length. It is supported, but only in recent Java versions.

You may use a pattern based on the [`\G` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html):

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\bpassport\b).*?\b([a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZV0su/1). *Pattern details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\bpassport\b)` - either a whole word *passport* (`\bpassport\b`) or (`|`) the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`)
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible (since the pattern is compiled with `Pattern.DOTALL`, the `.` can match any characters including line break characters)
- `\b([a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})\b` - a whole word that starts with zero, one or two ASCII letters, then has six to 12 digits and ends with zero, one or two ASCII letters.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ds9Vkh) below:

```java
String s = "my friends passport numbers are V123456, V123457 and V123458";
String rx = "(?:\\G(?!^)|\\bpassport\\b).*?\\b([a-zA-Z]{0,2}\\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rx, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Output:

```
V123456
V123457
V123458
```

Comment: Thank you, how can i ignore after a context ends. Ex:  my friends passport numbers are V123456, V123457 and V123458 also their visa numbers T123125,    in this case visa number shouldn't be extracted

Comment: @Satish It is possible with a tempered greedy token if your stop word is known: ``String rx = "(?:\\G(?!^)|\\bpassport\\b)(?:(?!\\bvisa\\b).)*?\\b([a-zA-Z]{0,2}\\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})\\b";``

Comment: Thank you its working as expected,  once quick question,  Can we do the same if the keyword after the pattern like "T123125 is my Visa number and V123456, V123457 and V123458 are my passport numbers"?

Comment: @Satish Yes, the trick is the same, but the pattern is different, `String rx = "(?i)\\b([a-z]{0,2}\\d{6,12}[a-z]{0,2})\\b(?=(?:(?!\\bvisa\\b).)*?\\bpassport\\b)";`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3vp5L/1).

Comment: thank you @Wiktor  </br>
in this regex (?:\G(?!\A)|\bpassport\b).*?\b([a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{6,12}[a-zA-Z]{0,2})\b  </br>
Can we tweak regex not to extract after 1st successful match if the subsequent passport numbers are connected by a word. </br>
Lets say 
Passport numbers V1256 , V1457 or V1458 also V1459  
In this case we should break extracting the passport numbers by when the words are connected by a specific words ex(, and)
Expected output (connected by , or) 
V1456 
V1457 
V1458  
Should not be extracted( due to also) 
V1459

Comment: @Satish Do you want to say the numbers are always separated with a comma or `and`/`or`? See https://regex101.com/r/lZV0su/2

Comment: Yes, thank you its really helpful

Comment: Looks like people here think otherwise.